# How to create Animation (changing Scaling, Rotation or Position) for a Node in ARCore Sceneform?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm using ARCore `Sceneform` libraries in Android Studio. I'm having trouble to find a method to perform a scaling animation to a node when it is set to enable (like the `Quaternion` used to rotate a node in Solar System by Google).

```
//On Tap Listener
scannerVisual.setOnTapListener(((hitTestResult, motionEvent) -> {

        // NodeAnimator arrow = new NodeAnimator(true);
        //arrow.setParent(scanner);

        Node arrowVisual = new Node();

        //StackOverflow Solution
        arrowVisual.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        arrowVisual.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.03f, 0.03f, 0.06f));
        arrowVisual.setRenderable(arrowRenderable);
        arrowVisual.setParent(scanner);

        // arrowVisual.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 90));
    })
);
```

I have something like this.

Comment: What have you changed your question for? I answered it. You should do it before any answer.

Comment: `"How to create animation..."` and `"Scaling animation..."` are different things!!!

Comment: Oh I'm So sorry for changing the question. I changed it because I wanted to create a scaling animation which I failed.. So I thought if I could get a solution for creating any animation, and learn how the logic works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a local scale of the node **`before`** setting its parent. The code should look like this:

```
Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

node.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.5f);
node.getScaleController().setMaxScale(3.0f);

node.setLocalScale(new Vector3(2.25f, 2.25f, 2.25f));
node.setParent(anchorNode);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the noob comment. I'm new to ARCore Sceneform.. getScaleController() will only work with TransformableNode. And I have already an anchorNode. Is it possible to have multiople anchors in one project? And another problem is where to create the ObjectAnimator and what values should I pass to ObjectAnimator.setObjectValues()..

Comment: Firstly: it is a set of different questions (it's too broad for one question). You may have any quantity of Anchors in your scene. So, please, publish a question for `getScaleController()`, second for `where to create the ObjectAnimator` and last for `ObjectAnimator.setObjectValues()`

Comment: Thanks, Is there any method like Quaternion to  do this?   Without using TransformableNode?

Comment: Here are node's getters and setter info –  https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/Node#getLocalScale()

Comment: Thanks.. It Worked